# How to INSERT into Postgres table with autogenerated id

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, insert

I'm trying to add into the table duplicate of current rows with some changes.

I have table with for example 3 colums (id, col1, col2), 
and 2 rows (492d0a75, some_text1, some_text2).

Colume Id of my table are not autoincremented, and i use:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid_gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid_gen", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "id", length = 36)
```

hibernate annotations to generate unic id.

Im want to do something like this:

```
insert into mytable(id, col1, col2)
select id, col1, 'other_value'
from mytable;
```

But can't do that becouse id will be not unic.

How can i do that?

Comment: `insert into mytable(col1, col2) select col1, 'other_value' from mytable`

Comment: @Andreas "Colume Id of my table are not autoincremented" this insert are not correct i will get "ERROR: a null value in the "id" column violates the NOT NULL constraint"

Comment: `MyEntity original = em.find(MyEntity.class, id); em.persist(new MyEntity(original.getCol1(), "other value");`

Comment: @JBNizet i`m trying to do that by flyway migration script

Comment: Then write your migration in Java to generate a UUID, or hard-code a pre-computed UUID in your migration script.

Comment: @RomanB Title says *"How to INSERT into Postgres table **with** autogenerated id"* Your question is contradicting itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, i'm install 'uuid-ossp'

To install the uuid-ossp module, you use the CREATE EXTENSION statement as follows:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

After that now i can use uuid_generate_v4() from [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/uuid-ossp.html)

And my final query looks like this:

```
insert into mytable (id, col1, col2)
select uuid_generate_v4(), col1, 'other_value'
from mytable;
```